# select option returns null on first click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a button to open a modal, inside the modal i have a select option

what i want is to get the value of select option every time i click the button..
the only problem that i always get is that on **first** click of button the value returns null on the second click i already get the value,

```
//select option inside the modal
<label>Type of Business</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="bus_type" id="bus_type">
        <option selected disabled>---</option>
            <?php 
              foreach ($result as $value) {
                echo "<option value=".$value['id'].">".strtoupper($value['name'])."</option>";
              }
            ?>                   
    </select>

 $(document).on('click', '.renew', function(){
        var value =  $('#bus_type').val();
        alert(value);
 });
```

Comment: .renew is the class of button

Comment: Posted code is not enough to answer this question as it can't have the described problem. Try to replicate the issue in demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.val() does not work with disabled selected options.

you could use `option:selected` as a work around, see https://jsfiddle.net/r7ue8qt5/

in the sample the second click doesn't work either, so i assume that the sample is not complete. therefore i think that after your first click you select another option which is not disabled or you remove the disabled attribute.